# Apache Tomcat Threads in WAITING state while thread pool increases

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am trying to analyse thread dumps I have taken from my tomcat server. One of the thread dumps was taken after a couple of minutes of uptime and shows a thread pool of about 70, with several in WAITING state. I left a script hitting the server overnight and when I took another thread dump in the morning. When comparing the two dumps I can see that the threadpool has increased to from 70 threads to 90 threads. I can also see that the same threads are in a WAITING state between one dump and the other, while 20 new threads are added. Would this suggest that there is some bug in my application or is this standard behavior? I am wondering why the threads that are in waiting are not being re-used and instead new threads being created. I am assuming that the threads have not been re-used at all from one dump to another because in the dump file it reports them as "waiting on " where the number in <> is the same from one dump to another, is this assumption correct?

For example, from my initial thread dump I see this:

```
"http-8000-40" - Thread t@74
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 - waiting on <4fd24389> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
  - None
```

and then I can see the same thread in the dump of the following morning in the same state and waiting on the same object: (I am assuming this from the numbers in "<>")

```
"http-8000-40" - Thread t@74
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <4fd24389> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
  - None
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat needs to spend some time managing threads and other resources even after your webapp's code completes processing a request. In order to keep up with the load, Tomcat will allocate new threads if enough aren't available.

If you have 70 total threads and 70 simultaneous requests, all should be well. If one request (of 70) completes (that is, the client has received all the data) and another is made before Tomcat is fully-done with the request-processor thread, another thread will be allocated to handle the new request resulting on a thread pool of size=71.

This can happen many times because it's not deterministic due to context switches, GC pauses, etc. that can interfere with exact timing of everything happening on the server.